# How to check the type of a nested property in mocha-chai?

Tags: node.js, testing, mocha.js, chai

Suppose the body of a response is something like that:

```
{
 "array": [
        {
            "porp1": {
                "subprop11": "a",
                "subprop12": [1,2]
            },
            "prop2": "c",
        },
        {
            "porp1": {
                "subprop11": "h",
                "subprop12": [3,2]
            },
            "prop2": "a",
        }
    ]
}
```

I know I can check that `prop1.subprop11` exists for all elements of the array in this way:

```
res.body['array'].should.all.have.nested.property('prop1.subprop11');
```

and I know I can test a non-nested property type as:

```
res.body['array'].to.be.a('array');
```

however I cannot concatenate the check of nested properties, i.e. I cannot do something like:

```
res.body['array'].should.all.have.nested.property('prop1.subprop11').that.is.a("string");
```

or something similar.

How can I check it is a string?

Answer (score 0):

I might be late, you can use for loop for testing itself(not the best but works)

```
for (const { prop1, prop2, prop3} of data) {
  const Id = generateID(index, timeStamp)
  expect("someprop").to.have.nested.property('prop1.subprop11').that.is.a("string");
}
```